# Зачем в названии функции на C++ столько двоеточий?

Tags: c++

```
void my_namespace::object::output_info(wfstream & wfst)
```

почему название этой функции такое большое?
зачем двоеточия?

Comment: Указаны пространства имен. Или, теоретически, класс - если это статическая функция-член :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::` означает, что имя (которое справа от `::`) нужно искать внутри класса/пространства имен/... (которое указано слева от `::`).

Судя по названиям, `my_namespace` - пространство имен, в нем есть класс `object`, а в нем метод `output_info`.

Указывать `ИмяКласса::` нужно, когда метод определяется отдельно от класса, пример:

```
class A
{
  public:
    void foo();
};

// Возможно в другом файле:
void A::foo() {...}
```

Указывать `ПространствоИмен::` можно вместо того, чтобы заворачивать функкцию в `namespace ПространствоИмен {...}`.

Например этот код:

```
void my_namespace::object::output_info(wfstream & wfst) {...}
```

можно заменить на:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    void object::output_info(wfstream & wfst) {...}
}
```

Но это работает только если функция уже объявлена. Пример:

```
// Без этой строки работать не будет:
namespace A {void foo();}

void A::foo() {...}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

`::` - это оператор, который используется для уточнения (квалификации) имен.

Бинарный оператор `::` уточняет область видимости в которой находится имя.
С левой стороны должна быть указана область видимости, с правой стороны - уточняемое имя.

Предполагаю что здесь используется пространство имен, внутри которого используется объект с указанным методом.